# Django: combine two ForeignKeys into one field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I need to implement the following:

The user shall be presented with a form that will have a drop down choice menu consisting of property names. There are two types of properties: general properties, i.e. properties common for all users and custom properties, i.e. properties that each user has defined prior to that. The models would look something like that:

```
class GeneralPropertyName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CustomPropertyName(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The drop down menu should have all general properties and only those custom properties that pertain to the user.

First question: how to define such a model? 
I need to: 1. somehow unify both properties, 2. take only those items from CustomPropertyName that pertain to the user

```
class SpecData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    selection_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    property = ForeignKey(GeneralPropertyName)  ??UNIFY??? ForeignKey(CustomPropertyName)
```

Second, is there anything special that needs to be done with ModelForm?

```
class SpecDataForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SpecData
```

And the 3rd question is what needs to be done in the view? I will need to use inline formsets since I will have a few dynamic forms like that.

```
def index(request):

    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

    specdataFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, SpecData, form=SpecDataForm, extra=30)

    ...     

    specdata_formset = specdataFormSet(instance=user, prefix='specdata_set')

    ...
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Adjusted juliocesar's suggestion to include formsets. Somehow I am getting the following error message: Cannot resolve keyword 'property' into field. Choices are: id, name, selection_title, user

```
def index(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username) 
    user_specdata_form = UserSpecDataForm(user=user)
    SpecdataFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, SpecData, form=user_specdata_form, extra=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) to handle it, but you still need more to solve your further questions about forms and view.

I have made an example of how you solve your problem (logged user can select from General properties and his Custom properties, non-logged user only can select General properties). I used model inheritance for the properties (In your sample code it seems that a `CustomPropertyName` is a `PropertyName` with other fields). I think inheritance is an easier and a more basic concept than ContentTypes and it fits to your needs.

*NOTE: I remove some code like imports to simplify the code.*

**1) models.py file:**

```
class PropertyName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomPropertyName(PropertyName): # <-- Inheritance!!
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class SpecData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    selection_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    property = models.ForeignKey(PropertyName)
```

*NOTES: The field `SpecData.property` points to PropertyName since all properties are saved in the PropertyName's database table.*

**2) forms.py file:**

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q
from models import SpecData, PropertyName

def UserSpecDataForm(user=None):

    UserPropertiesQueryset = PropertyName.objects.filter(Q(custompropertyname__user=None) | Q(custompropertyname__user__id=user.id))

    class SpecDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
        property = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserPropertiesQueryset)

        class Meta:
            model = SpecData
            exclude = ('user',)

    return SpecDataForm
```

*NOTES: The trick here is to generate the form `SpecDataForm` dynamically, by filtering properties according the user specified in the parameter.*

**3) views.py file:**

```
from forms import UserSpecDataForm

def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = UserSpecDataForm(request.user)(request.POST)  # instance=user
        if form.is_valid():
            spec_data = form.save(commit=False)
            spec_data.user = request.user
            spec_data.save()
    else:
        form = UserSpecDataForm(request.user)()
    return render_to_response('properties.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*NOTES: Nothing special here, just a call to `form.UserSpecDataForm(request.user)` that returns the form class and then instantiate. Also setted the logged-in user to the object returned on `save` since It was excluded in the `form` to not show in front-end.*

Following this basic example you can do the same with formsets if you need it.

**UPDATE:**

Formset can be used by adding following code to the view:

```
user_specdata_form = UserSpecDataForm(user=request.user)
SpecdataFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, SpecData, form=user_specdata_form, extra=30)
```

The complete project sample can be downloaded from http://ge.tt/904Wg7O1/v/0

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying your suggestion with formsets: see "EDIT" above in the question. Somehow, I get the following error: Cannot resolve keyword 'property' into field. Choices are: selection_title, id, name, user. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: I added your code in my example and it worked, so maybe you have missed something in other place, I uploaded the proyect to http://ge.tt/904Wg7O1/v/0 so you can test it and compare with your code, run the django server and access to the root page and you will the 30 forms of the formset. I removed `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` since it isn't necesary and generate an error when no user is logged.

Comment: I gave you the bounty. I still have some issues with saving the field as it fails saying "The field is required", but overall it looks like your solution is working. Thanks.

Comment: I created a SO question where I have a problem with formset for this solution and it has the entire code, so it is easy to check. Could you help me again? Thanks in any case. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274895/saving-formset-with-drop-down-menu-foreignkey-integrityerror-xxx-id-may-not-be

Answer (score 1):

1a) have you looked into django's [ContentType framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) this will allow you to have generic foreign keys and you can put restrictions on what types of models are acceptable to store in.

1b)  I think that the validation for accepting what type of foreign key is acceptable shouldn't be in your model but should be part of your form validation before saving.

2) If you do use a model form you're going to have to define your own [custom widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) for the propery field. This means you're probably going to have to write you're own render function to render the html from the field.  You should also define your own validation function on the form to make sure that only the appropriate data is acceptable to save.

3) I don't think you'll have to do anything you aren't already doing in the views

Answer (score 1):

Use GenericForeignKey:

```
class SpecData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    selection_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    property = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

You can use [this](http://adamalton.blogspot.com/2014/02/displaying-django-genericforeignkey-as.html) to combine the two fields(type & id) into a single choice field.

Answer (score 1):

One way is that you have only one model, make user nullable:

```
class PropertyName(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class SpecData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    selection_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    property = ForeignKey(PropertyName)
```

So, if user is not set, it is a general property. If it is set, it is related to this user.

However, please note that if you need unique property names, that NULL != NULL.

Of course, the suggested GenericForeignKey solution is better for some cases.

Also, you can easily make the normal (non-model) form with that you describe and separate form logic from model logic.