# Saving formset with drop-down-menu Foreignkey: IntegrityError XXX_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys, inline-formset

I am trying to have a formset where each form (PropertySelector) has a drop-down menu (PropertySelector.property) whereas each item of that menu is ForeignKey reference to another model (Property).

Somehow when I am trying to submit and save the formset I am getting:

```
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    testproj_propertyselector.property_id may not be NULL
```

What is wrong with it and how can I get around it? My entire code is below. Thanks.

**EDIT:** it looks like inline_formset problem to me (maybe MySQL also). Please, help me with workaround.

The project is called testproj and my app is called testproj too.

First we populate Property:

```
>>> from testproj.models import Property
>>> p = Property(name='prop1', basic=True)
>>> p.save() 
>>> p = Property(name='prop2', basic=True)
>>> p.save()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class PropertySet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    basic = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class PropertySelector(models.Model):
    property_set = models.ForeignKey(PropertySet)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select, ModelChoiceField
from django.db.models import Q
from testproj.models import Property, PropertySet, PropertySelector

class PropertySetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PropertySet

def PropertySelForm():
    PropertyQueryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(basic=True))

    class PropertySelectorForm(ModelForm):
        property = ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=PropertyQueryset,
            widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'property'})
        )

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.css_class = "prop_sel"

        class Meta:
            model = PropertySelector
            fields = ("property_set", "title")
            widgets = {"title" : TextInput(attrs={"class" : "title"})}

    return PropertySelectorForm
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from testproj.models import PropertySet, PropertySelector
from testproj.forms import PropertySetForm, PropertySelForm, PropertySelForm

def index(request):

    property_selector_form = PropertySelForm()
    PropertySelectorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(PropertySet, PropertySelector, form=property_selector_form)

    if request.method == "POST":

        property_set_form = PropertySetForm(request.POST)

        if property_set_form.is_valid():            
            saved_property_set = property_set_form.save()

            prop_sel_formset = PropertySelectorFormSet(request.POST, instance=saved_property_set)

            if prop_sel_formset.is_valid():
                prop_sel_formset.save()

        else:

            property_set_form = PropertySetForm()

            prop_sel_formset = PropertySelectorFormSet()    

        return render_to_response(
            "testproj/index.html",
            {
                "property_set_form": property_set_form,
                "prop_sel_formset": prop_sel_formset
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

index.html (template):

```
{% block content %}

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action=""> {% csrf_token %}

    {{ property_set_form.as_p }}

    {{ prop_sel_formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in prop_sel_formset %}
        {{ form }}

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Looks like you're modeling a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate model. You can use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) with a `through` parameter for that.

Comment: I do not view it as ManyToMany, at least it is not how I designed it. It is just that PropertySelect has two foreignKeys: PropertySet and Property, so there are two ManyToOne relationships.

Comment: I think the problem is that inline_formset takes only one ForeignKey as an argument and I do not know how to get around it.

Comment: Anyway, I modified the code to have ManyToManyField with _through_ parameter and I am getting the same error message. As I mentioned above it looks like inline_formset problem to me (maybe MySQL also)?

Comment: hmm I'm using `through` with inlines in the admin, and they work fine.

Comment: Here is my confusion: if PropertySelector.property is a drop-down menu that selects only property name (and not the id), how is the form supposed to know its **id** when saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property_id` isn't saved because you don't include it in your `form.Meta`. Leave away the fields, and it works:

```
def PropertySelForm():
    PropertyQueryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(basic=True))

    class PropertySelectorForm(ModelForm):
        property = ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=PropertyQueryset,
            widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'property'})
        )

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.css_class = "prop_sel"

        class Meta:
            model = PropertySelector
            #fields = ("property_set", "title")
            widgets = {"title" : TextInput(attrs={"class" : "title"})}

    return PropertySelectorForm
```

I'd rename `PropertySelForm` to `property_selectorform_factory`, but that's
just me. :)

Comment: PropertySelForm() is a function that returns ModelForm. No problem here.

Comment: I see. I was blinded by the CamelCase. Guess I've had a pep8 overdose.

Comment: If what you do in `PropertySelForm` should hold for all `PropertySelector`s you can set it on your model with `property = models.ForeignKey(Property, limit_choices_to=Q(basic=True))`

Comment: In real app it is a bit more involved as I will be using Q(basic=True) | Q(user=user)

Comment: Ah, and `user` is of course unknown at model loading time.

Comment: No, in the real app the user is known. I just provided a simplified example that has the same problem even without the user. If one copy-pastes it and tries it, it is supposed to give the "...property_id may not be NULL" error

Comment: If user is request.user, it isn't known in models.py...  But your example was just a url.py short of being [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), :-). Have you tried my edit?

Comment: For the "user" code I have:  **def PropertySelForm(user=None):
 PropertyQueryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(basic=True) | Q(user=user))**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49599/discussion-between-chris-wesseling-and-gregory-r)